# Request for two articles on conformal transformations

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, manifolds, paper-request

I am looking for two articles for my research purpose. The first one is entitled with "Invariant metrics for groups of conformal transformations" (1993, preprint) by K. R. Gutschera and the second one "Transformations conformes et quasi-conformes des variétés riemanniennes compactes" (1971) by J. Lelong-Ferrand.

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me to have these papers. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I have a PDF copy of the Gutschera article. Contact me through my webpage linked on my profile, and I'll send it to you.

Comment: I did contact you via the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Boy I gave it quite a try and they are indeed very hard to find.

If you are affiliated with a college/university -- or an institution that can make "inter-library loan"-type requests -- perhaps reach out to a librarian and see what they can do?

If not, maybe see if a public library near you can help you track it down?

Apologies if these suggestions aren't very helpful. The subject matter of these articles are *definitely* very far from the fields I specialize in; that being said, someone who *is* in that field may know where to look better than I do :-) Best of luck, I hope you will be able to track them down.

**Edit: Lelong-Ferrand (1971) has an entry on [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/transformations-conformes-et-quasi-conformes-des-varietes-riemanniennes-compactes-demonstration-de-la-conjoncture-de-a-lichnerowicz/oclc/6002166)**, which lists the libraries that have this article! Many libraries do provide scanning services, too. (However, gaining access to that may depend on you being affiliated with their library )